# C# movement limit snake game

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm a new programmer and I wanted to create a snake game for fun and to learn.

This is my code for movement:

```
private Vector2 _direction = Vector2.right;

private void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.W))
    {
        _direction = Vector2.up;
    }
    else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.S))
    {
        _direction = Vector2.down;
    }
    else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.D))
    {
        _direction = Vector2.right;
    }
    else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.A))
    {
        _direction = Vector2.left;
    }
}
```

I wanted to add a code that if the snake was moving up, it does not move down, or if it was moving left does not move right, and other directions.

And I wanted to know how to call arrows for movement.

So what do I do?

Thanks for helping <3 I just joined stack overflow :)

Comment: Well you already have access to the current direction of the snake (`_direction`), and you know which key was pressed, so can't you just put that together in the same if statements?

Comment: What have you tried and what isn't working?

Comment: i have not tried anything but i think i have to add an other if in keycode if 
and say like if (-direction = vector2.up)
{
stop the S button if pressed ? 
}

Comment: i just do not know how to do that

Comment: @BaRuti: What specifically do you not know how to do?  Before you set the new `_direction` value, you want to check if the current `_direction` value is a specific value, right?  And so you only conditionally update it to a new value.  Have you tried writing an `if` statement for that?  What specifically do you "not know how to do"?  When you *try*, what specifically doesn't work as expected?

Comment: @David i know what should i do i mean i know how should i write an if but i do not know what should i write in it to disable S button when i press W .

Comment: im sorry for not being clear ... pardon me for my poor choice of words

Comment: @BaRuti: What do you mean by "disable the S button"?  Isn't the user physically pressing the S key on their keyboard?  You can't modify the physical structure of their keyboard to prevent them from pressing one of the keys.  But you *can* determine in your code how you respond to that key press event.  Think about it semantically... "If the user presses W **and the current direction is not down**, change the current direction to up."

Comment: @David : this is what i want "If the user presses W change the current direction to up , but then if the user presses S dont change the current direction to down "

so like im the snake and im moving up
i have to just move left or right or just go up 
i have to be unable to move down

Comment: @BaRuti: *"if the user presses S dont change the current direction to down"* - That logic, by itself, would prevent the user from ever changing the direction to down.  Instead of simply saying "don't change the current direction to down", instead think of it as "only change the current direction to down **if the current direction is not up**".  To check that condition you would write an `if` statement in which you examine the current direction.  You are really, *really* encouraged to *try that*.

Comment: @David : that is it , thank you for helping and im sorry for not being clear im just a beginner , so is there a rating point to give to you ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private Vector2 _direction = Vector2.right;

int currentdirection = 1;
//0-up , 1-right, 2-down, 3-left

private void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.W) && currentdirection != 2  )
    {
        _direction = Vector2.up;
        currentdirection = 0;
    }
    else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.S))
    {
        _direction = Vector2.down;
        currentdirection = 2;
    }
    else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.D))
    {
        _direction = Vector2.right;
        currentdirection = 1;
    }
    else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.A))
    {
        _direction = Vector2.left;
        currentdirection = 3;
    }
}
```

This is the start of a simple solution. It has an int that keeps track of the direction the snake is moving. The if statement at the top has been modified to only change direction if the W key is pressed AND the current direction is not down. You can add something similar to the other three if statements.